# Live Chart is not rendering on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, livecharts

I have followed the below mentioned link to generate an image of live graph in my application and it is working fine on my local machine but when I deploy it on azure it is not doing anything. I am getting an empty image that does not contains graph in it further I have checked in logs no error or exception is being thrown. It seems that it is not working on Azure.

https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/blob/develop/Examples/Wpf/CartesianChart/Chart%20to%20Image/ChartToImageSample.xaml.cs

I can reproduce the issue on my local environment now by just commenting the following line of code:

myChart.Update(true, true); //force chart redraw
viewbox.UpdateLayout();

It seems that control cannot be updated on Azure. I have also tried to update the controls through "Dispatcher" but still getting the same issue on Azure.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: When you say deployed to azure atre ytou talking about azure webapps or azure vm or containers?

Comment: I am using this LiveChart library in Microsoft Bot Framework (Web API) and deployed it on azure.

Comment: Do you convert the chart to image and sender to user within bot?

Comment: Yes I am changing the chart to image with the same logic mentioned in above link.

Answer (score 1):

I create a test sample on my side, I find the code that is used to generate image for **LiveChart** can work in Bot application on Azure.

***Installed following LiveCharts and LiveCharts.Wpf NuGet***

```
<package id="LiveCharts" version="0.9.7" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="LiveCharts.Wpf" version="0.9.7" targetFramework="net46" />
```

***Create a Bot Application project and Put the code of generating image for LiveChart in Bot Application*** (*if possible, you can recreate a new Bot Application and test the following code to check if it works for you*)

```
string sfp = "";

private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    var activity = await result as Activity;

    // calculate something for us to return
    int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;
    sfp = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"~/IMG/chart.png");

    Thread STAThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var myChart = new LiveCharts.Wpf.CartesianChart
        {
            DisableAnimations = true,
            Width = 600,
            Height = 200,
            Series = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> {1, 6, 7, 2, 9, 3, 6, 5}
                }
            }
        };

        var viewbox = new System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox();
        viewbox.Child = myChart;
        viewbox.Measure(myChart.RenderSize);
        viewbox.Arrange(new System.Windows.Rect(new Point(0, 0), myChart.RenderSize));
        myChart.Update(true, true); //force chart redraw
        viewbox.UpdateLayout();

        SaveToPng(myChart, "chart.png");
    });

    STAThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    STAThread.Start();

    STAThread.Join();

    await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters1");

    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

**Note**: in my test, I create `IMG` folder manually via Kudu Console, not create it in code.

***Test in Web Chat and send a message to Bot, and then check site folder, can find the image `chart.png` is generated via [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)***

[image]

***chart.png***

[image]

Besides, I send image as an attachment to client with the following test code, the chart.png can be rendered fine in client side.

```
var replymes = context.MakeMessage();

replymes.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
{
    Name = "chart.png",
    ContentType = "image/png",
    ContentUrl = "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/IMG/chart.png"
});

await context.PostAsync(replymes);
```

[image]